# Changing manifest meta-data from code

Tags: android, android-manifest

I have a app that uses ads.
The ad id is set in the manifest id with a meta-data tag.

I want to change this tag when i start the app in some cases
(diferent id for some localisations)

Can i do this in code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The manifest meta-data can't be changed at runtime.

You should look to see if your ad library allows direct setting of the advertiser id (e.g. AdMobs SDK has an AdManager class which allows the setting of things that can be defined in the metadata).

Comment: Thanks.

My lib does not allow that.
So had to build two versions.
But problem solved.