# Accessing Amazon Kindle Sidebar - Xamarin.Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Does anyone know how to access the sidebar on Amazon Kindle Fire HD tablet? The sidebar seems to be a feature, specific to Kindle (I didn't find it on a Samsumg Galaxy tablet).

What happens is that if my activity allows searching, then the search also becomes accessible through the sidebar, as illustrated by the attached screenshot. But there are circumstances, when I want to disable search. I can do this perfectly fine with the search icon within the activity menu (disabling the menu item), but how do I access the sidebar?

Hope I explained it clearly enough.

[image]

My manifest bit for the activity looks like this:

```
[Activity(Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Holo", LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTop, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape)]
[IntentFilter(new[] { Intent.ActionSearch, Intent.ActionView })]
[MetaData(name: "android.app.searchable", Resource = "@xml/searchable")]
[MetaData(name: "android.app.default_searchable", Value = ".ReportingActivity")]
```

Removing either 2nd or 3rd line results in the sidebar search still being there, but now allowing to search the Amazon app store instead of my app, while all I want is just it being disabled or removed entirely. This has to be done dynamically from code based on some conditions. Nonetheless, apparently, manifest cannot be modified dynamically as per the following:

[Changing manifest meta-data from code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174424/changing-manifest-meta-data-from-code)

Plus I tried it myself via:

```
PackageManager.GetActivityInfo(ComponentName, PackageInfoFlags.Activities | PackageInfoFlags.MetaData).MetaData.Clear();
```

Which results in nothing.

So, any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Thanks!