# How to populate AndroidManifest meta-data value programatically?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-intent, android-manifest

**I understand the `AndroidManifest.xml` is prepared at compile time and not runtime**, is there any other way to populate metadata in the manifest without relying on hard coded strings? Maybe populating it somehow at compile time?

I currently have the following on my `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/dt_icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data
        android:name="DataPath"
        android:value=""
     /> ...
```

I don't want to hard code the value and instead populate it somehow with the results from:

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

Another application will later retrieve the value of `DataPath` by utilizing the `ApplicationInfo`'s metaData property.

Comment: I think you can't change meta-data value at runtime AFAIK

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing manifest meta-data from code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3174424/changing-manifest-meta-data-from-code)

Comment: @Shubham The first thing i wrote "I understand the AndroidManifest.xml is prepared at compile time and not runtime," I'm looking for an alternative, I believe i read somewhere that its possible to assign the value at compile time but still not hard coding it...

Answer (score 3):

> I believe i read somewhere that its possible to assign the value at compile time but still not hard coding it

The best you can do is to assign a value from gradle via [manifest placeholders](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-build-variables.html).

Example:

```
android {
    defaultConfig {
        manifestPlaceholders = [hostName:"www.example.com"]
    }
    ...
}

<intent-filter ... >
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="${hostName}" ... />
    ...
</intent-filter>
```